# What is wrong with my Cloud Firestore set opertion

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Starter with Cloud Firestore this week and going trough the docs.
I´m doing something wrong here because the below code run but no Success or Failure listener are firing and no writes at [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

I am connected ok because before this I run a [Cloud Firestore Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) and it completes successfully. I can see in the `https://console.firebase.google.com` the result of the Transaction.

Here´s the code that run but nothing happens:

```
final Map<String, Object> userHistoryMap = new HashMap<>();
userHistoryMap.put(History.ADDRESS_ID, "test1");
userHistoryMap.put(History.TIME, FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

DocumentReference newRef = mFirestore.collection(USER_HISTORY).document();

newRef.set(userHistoryMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        LogManager.d(this, "user history was saved");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        LogManager.report(new AddUserHistoryException("test");
    }
});
```

I see no error in logcat nothing I restart Android studio (3.0) and laptop nothing helps. Feels like a missed something brutally obvious ..:)

I did get at the same time randomly warning messages from Android Studio that the file(java file) holding this code was not saved and I hade to choose between load/revert something..maybe that´s why the breakpoint or code not running

UPDATE: 
Moving the code above to another source file like a `Fragment` and the code run perfectly. I search the [bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:(192786%20%7C%20192805%20%7C%20192705%20%7C%20192792%20%7C%20192644%20%7C%20192694%20%7C%20192710%20%7C%20192810%20%7C%20192634%20%7C%20192698%20%7C%20192706%20%7C%20192815%20%7C%20192715%20%7C%20192720%20%7C%20192711%20%7C%20192629%20%7C%20192643%20%7C%20192693%20%7C%20192639)) but find nothing. The source code file has become stale somehow but I can build and run debug on a real device and other methods in the source file still works

UPDATE:
Now it happens again the source file i´m working on cant be saved. Including a picture:

[image]

UPDATE: Whenever I get the above error message in the picture I copy the code ctrl+c to Notepad++ and paste it back in because the bottom code in the java file is always missing. Maybe I should reinstall Androis Studio hehe

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some syntax error in you code. Try this,

```
final Map<String, Object> userHistoryMap = new HashMap<>();
userHistoryMap.put(History.ADDRESS_ID, "test1");
userHistoryMap.put(History.TIME, FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

DocumentReference newRef = mFirestore.collection(USER_HISTORY);

newRef.add(userHistoryMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        LogManager.d(this, "user history was saved");
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        LogManager.report(new AddUserHistoryException("test");
    }
});
```

I am not that sure, but try it anyway.

Comment: Think I tried that yea `DocumentReference` does not have `add()` and `newRef` is not a ` CollectionReference` . I ended up putting the code in a Transaction and it was actually what I needed. Th strange "cannot save file error" did not come back today thank god